# Resource nesting with tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Trying to do something pretty simple with tastypie, but cannot figure out how. Lets say I have a model Author and a mode Book with a foreign key pointing to author. And I have an Author resource. So, /api/v1/author would get me a list of authors and /api/v1/author/1 would get me details on a particular author. I want /api/v1/author/1/books to get me a list of books for this particular author. How?

Example code:

`from django.db import models
from tastypie.resource import ModelResource`

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author')

class AuthorResource(ModelResource):
    queryset = Author.objects.all()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the recipe for this was actually in the cookbook, but for something so obvious, the implementation is rather awkward.

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#nested-resources